# How to get content of "id"

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

I want to get 2016 out of this id or the "year of" out of Years.

```
<tr id="2016" Years="year of" style>
```

I want to scrape the 2016, how would I do this? considering there is multiple "id" on the page?
I have tried:

```
year = driver.find_element_by_id("id")
```

i am using requests, selenium and phantomJS

Comment: Anybody have any idea what to do? Here's something similar I want to scrape. 

<option value="XXX" able="5" froze="12" status="True" text="13.5">

I want to get the XXX

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.get_attribute('id')` to get any attributes present in the element.

```
year = driver.find_element_by_id("id").get_attribute('id') ## Return ID as string.
```

You can find more information about getting element attributes from HTML tags in the [Webdriver docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute)

Comment: How would i find the element: Years
find_element_by_id only works for id

Answer (score 1):

You can use get_attribute("id") or get_attribute("Years") to extract "2016" or "year of" respectively.

Below is the code you can use :

```
year = driver.find_element_by_id("2016").get_attribute("id")
```

or

```
string = driver.find_element_by_id("2016").get_attribute("Years")
```

Comment: How would i find the element: Years find_element_by_id only works for id